# prevent child components from rerendering whem making changes to parent state

Tags: reactjs

So I have a spinner in my child component where whenever the parent component updates its state it rerenders everything including the child, which makes the child component's spinner appear on every change in state from the parent.

Is there a way to prevent this so that the spinner will only appear on certain changes to the parent state?

Comment: The easiest way I would suggest is to add a flag showSpinner in the state which will have a boolean value. If it is set to true show the spinner else don't show. This way you can implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're passing the parent state as a prop to the child. You can use the [ShouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle method to prevent the child from re-rendering when the prop coming from the parent doesn't require the child to be updated.

Comment: It doesn't 100% guarantee children from rerendering.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what your code looks like but as I see it you have two options:

- Do a validation in shouldComponentUpdate() - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate
- If that isn't enough you can add a variable to your state dictating if spinner should be visible or not:

```js
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { showSpinner: true }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    myAsyncFetch.done((data) => {
      this.setState({ showSpinner: false })
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    if (this.state.showSpinner) {
      return <Spinner/>;
    }
    
    return <div/>; // Content
  }
}
```